How to optimize query to get latest data from transaction table in PostgreSQL with SQLAlchemy without response delay?
How to optimize query to get latest data from transaction table in PostgreSQL with SQLAlchemy without response delay?
I'm working on a demo system using PostgreSQL and SQLAlchemy in Python. In this system, the transaction table processes approximately 200 transactions per second (TPS) during normal hours and up to 400 TPS during peak hours.
I need to query the latest transaction data without causing delays in response time. Given the high volume of transactions, I'm concerned about potential performance issues that could result in slow query responses.
System Details:
Tech Stack: PostgreSQL, SQLAlchemy
Table Schema (transaction):
id (Primary Key)
created_unix_time (Big int)
Additional relevant fields
Objective: Query the most recent transaction record.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
    async def get_all_by_distinct_transaction_type(self, where: dict | None, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 10) -> List[TransactionModel]:
    try:
        if where is None:
            where = {}

        query = select(self.model_class)

        if where:
            condition = destruct_where(self.model_class, where)
            if condition is not None:
                query = query.where(condition)

        query = query.order_by(desc(self.model_class.id)
                               ).offset(skip).limit(limit)

        result = await self.session.execute(query)
        data = result.scalars().all()
        return data
    except Exception as e:
        log.error(f"Error get_all_by_distinct_transaction_type: {e}")
        raise InternalServer(
            error_code=ErrorCode.ERROR_EXECUTE_QUERY.name)

async def count_all_by_distinct_transaction_type(self, where: dict | None) -> int:
    try:
        query = select(self.model_class)
        if where is not None:
            condition = destruct_where(self.model_class, where)
            if condition is not None:
                query = query.where(condition)

        return await super()._count(query)
    except Exception as e:
        log.error(f"Error count_all_by_distinct_transaction_type: {e}")
        raise InternalServer(error_code=ErrorCode.ERROR_EXECUTE_QUERY.name)

In my project, I tried to retrieve the latest transaction record from a high-throughput PostgreSQL table using SQLAlchemy. I expected the query to return the most recent record quickly, even under heavy load. However, I’m concerned that the current approach, which involves ordering by timestamp and limiting the result to one, might cause performance issues and slow down as the transaction volume increases. I was hoping for a solution that would maintain fast response times, regardless of the high transaction rate.

Try a index on the table on created_unix_time. But that's a guess: you haven't shown us the SQL query generated by SQLAlchemy.

I'm sorry this is my lack of soat
